# Laravel Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined

Tags: laravel

I added 2 fields in a table. Nothing crazy
When i want to save() my object i get this error.

```
$annonce = new Annonce([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'slug' => uniqid(),
            'is_active' => false,
            'energie_ges' => $request->get('energie_ges'), //field i added
            'energie_dpe' => $request->get('energie_dpe'),//field i added
            'active_until' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        dd($annonce);//works

        $saved = $annonce->save(); //create the exception
```

I try to find out since 2 hours but i have no idea why.

I did a php artisan optimize and nothing change.

Thanks

Comment: can you please post that controller, the form that you are submitting, and the routes?

Comment: post your controller code.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia i added the part of code

Comment: @VikasKatariya i added the part of code

Comment: Ok great I just give you solutions .

Comment: hello can you please share code of your Annonce model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found. It was simple, just made a mistake in the name of the fields of my database i added in the migration file.

It was hard to find because the error of Laravel was wrong.

Comment: thank you this also solved my problem. Same error and when i went over my code i noticed some field names were declared different than the database.